# What's a good word for "to turn into a library"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word to describe the act of making something into a software library.

[Software libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) are collections of code with a well-defined interface, such that it is easy to integrate the library with other software. Making libraries is a common activity in software development. The actions involved are not well defined though; sometimes it is to extract a portion of a bigger software package into a form easily used by other software, sometimes it is to agglomerate a set of disparate pieces of software to use a common interface. Since the activity is defined by its end result, I was thinking of the made-up words [***librify***](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=librify) and [***librarify***](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=librarify) (since the [-ify suffix seems to fit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/ify)), but I see these words are very uncommon.

Is there an existing word that fits this definition? Perhaps one not in a dictionary but commonly used or well understood by the target audience?

Comment: Are you looking for something formal or something cute? I like librarify; I could see myself saying it at work. If you were trying to be clear in a document, stick with the longer description.

Answer (score 4):

**Packaging** sounds most correct to me. The most important defining property of a software library is that it's a self-contained, well, *package*.

Software libraries and the constructs used to organise and distribute them are often termed "packages": Here's [Java's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package), [Python's](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) and [Perl's](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html). Even languages that don't have them as an explicit language feature speak of "implementing packages" as [in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/15.html).

All of [a guide on "How to Package Your Python Code"](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/), a ["Lua Packaging Guide"](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaPackagingGuide) and [various questions on StackOverflow tagged "packaging"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packaging) use the word to mean putting code into a form useable by others.

Answer (score 3):

"Archiving", "linking", or perhaps "cataloguing"? The UNIX 'ar' tool (short for archiver) is used to build static libraries; and a linker is used to build dynamic (shared) libraries. These cover the technical side of creating a library.

If you're looking for a broader description of the whole process, "packaging" is probably the most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Anthologize.

> Our library anthologizes the source code from X and Y, in the form of a
>   port and a wrapper, respectively.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me the word "archiving" is appropriate

Comment: Why do you think that? "Archive" is not a word I would normally associate with a software library.

Answer (score -2):

Building or packaging come to mind. If you're taking from existing code converting or extracting sound fine too.

Comment: some explanations/examples would be helpful